# How to show a hidden form from a different form?

Tags: c#

I have a `Form1`, `Form2` and `Form3`, `Form1` being the main form.

The program starts at `Form1`, when I click a "next" button `Form2` is called and `Form1` hides.

Inside `Form1`:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
this.Hide();
form2.Show();
```

And inside `Form2` there's an "exit" and a "next" button. When I click on exit button, `Form2` is closed and goes back to `Form1`, unhiding it.

Inside `Form2` and inside partial class `Form2`:

```
private Form parent;
public Form2(Form caller)
{
    parent=caller;  
}
```

On exit button:

```
this.Close();
parent.show();
```

And at the "next" button of `Form2` I call `Form3` and close `Form2`:

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3();
this.Close();
form3.Show();
```

Now that I'm in `Form3` how can I unhide/show `Form1` from `Form3` ?

I know that I have to list here the solutions I've tried, but I'm just starting with OOP and I'm stuck trying to do this. I've tried several things but none of them make sense and don't know how to do this.

Just to clarify, I don't want to create a new instance of `Form1` I just want to Show the one that's already created.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Your form2 constructor takes a Form argument but when you make your `new Form2()` you do not supply it. Why? Typo? Two constructors? If your process works for Form1->2 why not just apply the same technique to Form3?

Comment: Also worth nothing there is a big difference between closing and hiding a form

Comment: Yes, sorry, had a typo in Form2 constructor. Form1 works like the index of a book, and Form2 and 3 are like pages, so the flow of the program is whenever you close a page you return to the Index.

Form2 is the "next" page from Index, but Form3 is the next page of Form2, that's why I can't make the same technique  to go from Form1 to Form3 when passing through Form2.

Comment: Sure you can; form2 knows about the index, so it can tell form3 the index. Any formX can go back to the index because at create time the formX that creates formX+1 knows the index and can tell the created form the index. The index is thus endlessly passed around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form1 should look like:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
this.Hide();
form2.Show();
```

Form2 should look like:

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3(parent);
this.Close();
form3.Show();
```

Your form2 knows about your form1 via the `parent` member, and it can hence give your form1 to Form3 (which should also have a constructor that takes a Form1)

Every form should have a constructor that takes a Form1 and stores it in a parent variable. Every form other than Form1 should pass the parent variable to any new form it creates

You can make this easier using inheritance for the ctor, the next and the close functionality

---

I do not recommend calling your class Form- call it Form1 so it doesn't clash with System.Windows.Forms.Form

Actually you should call them all something better- MainForm, CreatePersonForm and CreateAddressForm for example

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't figure you could pass Form1 to all other forms that way, but I get it now. I really appreciate the help, and definitely will take your advice. Thanks again :)